# Extra TinyMCE editor strips <p> and <br> tags?

Tags: editor, tinymce, line-breaks

Hey guys, I've added a TinyMCE to some textareas that are displayed in a custom meta box. All of the formatting works perfectly fine, except that the editor will not save `<p>` or `<br/>` tags. It doesn't preserve the line breaks.

The TinyMCE is setup like this:

```
wp_tiny_mce(true, array('editor_selector' => $field['class'] ) );

'<textarea name="', $field['id'], '" class="', $field['class'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" cols="60" rows="8" style="width:97%">', $meta ? esc_html($meta) : $field['std'], '</textarea>';
```

And that all works perfectly fine. All the formatting buttons work fine, except for the `<P>` and `<BR>` tags.

I'm not sure if the editor is stripping them out before or after the post meta is saved.

Ideas?

Comment: I managed to get it to work in one way. By duplicating the function from core, and changing `'remove_linebreaks' => true` to `'remove_linebreaks' => false`. But it doesn't work if I specify `'remove_linebreaks' => false` in the settings array passed to the function

Comment: @Arthur Carabott yes, that did the trick for me too. Let's add a link to the docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop Bye!

Comment: We're seeing a very weird thing. Posts that are hand-entered/copy-pasted have the breaks preserved on edit.  Posts that we imported are subject to the editor blowing away the line breaks on edit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I recently got this working. You should search and replace `metaname` with your meta box name.

The key to maintaining formatting was using `wpautop();` when saving the data.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_metaname_box');

add_action( 'save_post', 'metaname_save');

function add_metaname_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'metaname_id',
        __( 'metaname text', 'metaname_textdomain'),
        'metaname_custom_box',
        'page'
    );
}

function metaname_custom_box() {
    global $post;
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'metaname_noncename' );
    $data = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'metaname_custom_box', true);
    echo <<<EOT
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#metaname_custom_box").addClass("mceEditor");
    if ( typeof( tinyMCE ) == "object" &&
         typeof( tinyMCE.execCommand ) == "function" ) {
        tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, "metaname_custom_box");
    }
});
</script>
    <textarea id="metaname_custom_box" name="metaname_custom_box">$data</textarea>
EOT;
}

function metaname_save($post_id) {
    global $post;

    // Verify
     if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['metaname_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
         return $post_id;
     }
     if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
         if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ))
             return $post_id;
     } else {
         if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ))
             return $post_id;
     }

     $key = 'metaname_custom_box';
    $data = wpautop($_POST[$key]);

     // New, Update, and Delete
     if(get_post_meta($post_id, $key) == "") 
         add_post_meta($post_id, $key, $data, true);
     elseif($data != get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true))
         update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $data); 
     elseif($data == "")
         delete_post_meta($post_id, $key, get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true));        
}
```

Comment: `update_post_meta` will also `add_post_meta` if the `meta_key` to be inserted does not exist.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to have changed a little in subsequent versions of Wordpress. You can now disable this functionality thusly:

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', function($init) {
    $init['wpautop'] = false;
    return $init;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's (a pared-down version of) what I use to custom-configure TinyMCE:

```
// http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration
function cbnet_tinymce_config( $init ) {

    // Don't remove line breaks
    $init['remove_linebreaks'] = false; 

    // Pass $init back to WordPress
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'cbnet_tinymce_config');
```

I assume this is what you tried already?

EDIT:

You may need to include some other config changes, such as:

```
// Convert newline characters to BR tags
$init['convert_newlines_to_brs'] = true; 
// Do not remove redundant BR tags
$init['remove_redundant_brs'] = false;
```

Play around with the [TinyMCE configuration parameters](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration), and find the one that you need to change.

Comment: No, I didn't use that. How would I filter my wp_tiny_mce with your function?

Comment: Drop the code in `functions.php`.

Comment: Hmmm, that's not working.

Comment: See my edit. You may not be targeting the correct configuration parameter.

Comment: Hmm, still no luck. As far as I can tell, the filter isn't making any effect at all. This is for a plugin, so the filter code is placed in the main plugin file. Does it possibly need to be passed through an init hook?

Comment: It should already get hooked, into `tiny_mce_before_init`. You don't have it inside another function, or object, etc., do you?

Answer (score 3):

Found perhaps a simpler workaround for this:

on the actual template, change this:

```
<?php echo get_the_content());?>
```

to this:

```
<?php echo wpautop(get_the_content());?>
```

This way wpautop() *adds* the tags stripped out by TinyMCE on a template by template basis.

Answer (score 2):

why not you use wordpress new function [`wp_editor`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) to render the tinymce. That way everything will get handled. And when you show the content to the user apply the filter `the_content`.

Like this:

```
$meta = "content of the metabox";
echo apply_filters('the_content', $meta);
```

The filter `the_content` will autmatically convert the link brakes to `<br>` and `<p>`.

Comment: At the time this question was posted, the wp_editor() function was not available.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution: Use Shortcodes!

Place this code into functions.php and use [br] in the content editor - HTML or visual - wherever you want a br tag to appear.

```
add_shortcode("br", "br_tag");

function br_tag(){
    return("<br/>");                            

}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is for who use the metaboxes for wordpress: 
Plugin Name: Meta Box
Plugin URI: deluxeblogtips com/meta-box

i have modify the /vendor/meta-box/inc/fields/wysiwyg.php 
in static function :

```
static function html( $html, $meta, $field )

//just after the else i have added :
$meta = html_entity_decode($meta); // 
//and solve the problem ;)
```

--  BUT THE BETTER SOLUTION IS --

Put this into functions.php, it calls the filter from the metaboxes pluggin:

```
function meta_wysiwyg_antes_save($meta)
{   
    $meta = html_entity_decode($meta);
    return $meta;
}
add_filter("rwmb_(ID-OF-METABOX-FIELD)_meta", "meta_wysiwyg_antes_save"); //en meta-box.php 194
```

Comment: Now you cannot update the plugin anymore. Not a good solution.

Comment: Have Some a little more constructive opinion? :) Where can i put this code on functions.php?

Comment: Hook into `save_post` earlier than the plugin and prepare the value in a separate function?