# Cannot get <p> tags working from a WPAlchemy metabox with wp_editor()

Tags: custom-field, tinymce, wp-autop, wpalchemy

I'm using WPAlchemy on a project.

For a template, I need to use a custom metabox which is working fine with a tinyMCE editor.

Code to insert the meta box on the template (this is a piece of code from https://github.com/helgatheviking/WP-Alchemy-Holy-Grail-Theme/ because I end up trying it after a looooog search, but *macache*).

```
<div class="my_meta_control metabox">
<p>
<?php $mb->the_field('richfield');

$settings = array(
'textarea_rows' => '10',
'media_buttons' => 'false',
'tabindex' =>2
);

$val = html_entity_decode($mb->get_the_value());   
$id = $mb->get_the_name();

wp_editor($val, $id , $settings );

?> 
</p>
<p class="meta-save"><button type="submit" class="button-primary" name="save"><?php _e('Update');?></button></p>

</div>
```

I have added the following in `functions.php`

```
/*
* Recreate the default filters on the_content
* this will make it much easier to output the meta content with proper/expected       formatting
*/
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'wptexturize' );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'convert_smilies' );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'convert_chars' );

//use my override wpautop
if(function_exists('override_wpautop')){
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'override_wpautop' );
} else {
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'wpautop' );
}
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'shortcode_unautop' );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'prepend_attachment' );
```

and for the output :

```
<div class="content-column content-tab content-richtext">
    <?php
    global $page_type_richtext;
    $page_type_richtext->the_meta(); // don't think I need this line
    $richtextcontent = $page_type_richtext->the_value( 'richfield' );
    echo apply_filters('meta_content', $richtextcontent );
    ?>
</div>
```

But I never manage to have the `<p>` tags working. I don't understand where i'm wrong.

I have tried a lot of different ways, using `the_content` filter, or `wpautop`but it's not working at all.

The display is perfect in the custom field itself inside the admin page. That's why I'm getting mad. The content is correctly `wpautop()` when in admin, so I guess the content is properly saved in DB. There must be a way to make it work, but I really don't know. I have find a couple of stack exchange questions about that, [like this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15394/extra-tinymce-editor-strips-p-and-br-tags) but I don't understand how to adapt it. Looks like I should use `wpautop` at the saving of the post, but this is handled by WPAlchemy, and `wp_editor()` doesn't need it, in theory as I understood it.

Does anyone give me a hind or a lead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry you were having trouble with my "Holy Grail".  It looks like you missed an important part in my functions.php sample:

`apply_filters('meta_content',$simple_textarea->get_the_value('test_editor'));`

You weren't using WP Alchemy's `get_the_value` method.  So instead of:

`$richtextcontent = $page_type_richtext->the_value( 'richfield' );`

yours should have been:

`$richtextcontent = $page_type_richtext->get_the_value( 'richfield' );`

You were using `the_value` which echos out the value and therefore doesn't give you a chance to run it through the filters.

The `meta_content` filters are not useless, but can be redundant.  You *can* use `the_content` filters, but a lot of plugins hook into `the_content`... (such as most social sharing plugins) and if you use `apply_filters('the_content',$sometext)` in a lot of places you can end up with a page full of social buttons!  I did once, which is why I decided it was cleaner to *duplicate* `the_content`.

I'm sure you aren't still working on this project, but hopefully this will help anyone else who ends up on this question.

Cheers!

Comment: Well, I make it works using `get_post_meta`but your answer tell me why it wasn't working in the first place. So I give your the answer !

Answer (score 0):

Ok I sort it out.

To let you know :

- The code to invocate the custom meta box is correct
- The filter part in `function.php` is perfectly useless -> all we have to do is use `apply_filters` with the $tag `the_content` which already use all the needed filters to properly echoing rich text content.
- So the problem was in using the built-in custom way WPAlchemy retrieves values. I just used core functions of Wordpress to get values (WPAlchemy is very well documented, so that was easy) and tadaaam! it worked. I guess the method `$page_type_richtext->the_value( 'richfield' )` just destroy breaklines, so there was no way the filter could insert `<p>` tag without these informations.

The correct way to output the data is, in my case :

```
<div class="content-column content-tab content-richtext">
    <?php
    global $page_type_richtext; // accessing meta data in global space 
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $page_type_richtext->get_the_id(), TRUE); // use get_post_meta to retrieve content 
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $meta['richfield'] ); // echo data processed with the_content filter
    ?>
</div>
```

Thanks.