# Stop editor from removing <p> tags and replacing them with nbsp

Tags: tinymce, wp-autop, line-breaks

When I enter content in posts/pages' WYSIWYG editor, I do not get `<p>` when ending paragraphs, just `&nbsp`s.  If I manually place `<p></p>` in the HTML mode, they are stripped as soon as I switch to 'visual' mode.
This is repeated in several sites (I thought it was the theme but it isn't).

I have read dozens of topics and answers, but none solve my problem.
I tried `add/remove wpautop` in my functions.php file but nothing helps.

I do not want to use a tinymce plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done extended research and found the answer - I am now using a hook on 'tiny_mce_before_init'.

Based on [other answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15666/12762) (special thanks to answer #2 [@Chip Bennett](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/3966/chip-bennett)), I have used the following code in my functions.php to secure the paragraph breaks (in the editor HTML mode they show as **&nbsp** but become paragraphs on the front-end):

```
function tinymce_config_59772( $init ) {
   // Don't remove line breaks
   $init['remove_linebreaks'] = false; 
   // Convert newline characters to BR tags
   $init['convert_newlines_to_brs'] = true; 
   // Do not remove redundant BR tags
   $init['remove_redundant_brs'] = false;

   // Pass $init back to WordPress
   return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'tinymce_config_59772');
```

You can find on the tinyMCE [site](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration) the different possible configurations.

Comment: function name shouldnt start with numbers. It throws error.

Answer (score 2):

you could also say that TinyMCE is integrated with WordPress and the HTML editor strips out some characters in favour `&nbsp` ... this was originally for security and the *belief* that we didnt need `<br>` or `<p>` anymore

Comment: oh how wrong they were....lol

Comment: @Aliyah I dont think they'll add it back again. It's been that way for years. FWIW ... I never knew CKEditor had been packaged for WordPress and I guess it is free?

Comment: Yea its in the WP plugins directory in the link I gave

Comment: wait a sec lol..is that your answer?

Comment: @Damien - that's a good explanation, any solutions?

Comment: Perhaps this editor plugin is a solution since your problem comes from your WYSIWYG :)

Comment: Same quality answers as the WP forum... **eye roll**

Answer (score 1):

You can try the CKEditor

[Wordpress CKEditor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/)

Comment: @aliyah- isn't there some code we can use? I don't like using plugins, because you never know how they'll affect other things.

Comment: @NonaMan Not every plugin has adverse effects on the site. Try it out and see if it solves your problem. This is simply an enhanced WYSIWYG editor plugin. It may or may not solve your problem, never hurts to try. You can always disable it. I'm using it now and the site runs smoothly. It doesnt make any serious changes.

Comment: This works and provides the editor with the ability to keep the paragraph tags.  Thankyou!    I do wish someone can write **a function that hooks onto the editor and changes the 'nbsp' to paragraph tags.**

Comment: @NonaMan Me too lol