# Stop wordpress from adding html tags but not remove my own tags?

Tags: tags, html, the-content, formatting

I've been trying to make wordpress stop adding html tags to my content but leave my own html tags alone?

Tried `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );`  and installed PS Disable Auto Formatting but the problem is that it removes my own html tags aswell?

I've tried to get_the_content() and the_content() but the same problem occurs there...

The way I wan't this to work is to let me add html tags and leave these alone, not removing them. Like this:

```
<p>Some text here</p>
<p>some more text <span class="fat"> fat </span></p>
```

Comment: > "Tried wp_autop thing ..." You mean something like this: `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` ?

Comment: Are you switching between Visual and HTML editors while editing posts?

Comment: No I wasn't but I just tried to deactivate the visual editor and now it works, I haven't touched the visual editor and think it's rather shitty to have a tabbed option where you can switch to html, but then it doesn't work...? So your only option is to either have the visual on or off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try accessing the $post object inside your loop, and echo'ing the content from that. Something like:

```
<?php echo $post->post_content ?>
```

#### Edit

If you need to parse shortcodes, use [**`do_shortcode()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode):

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( $post->post_content ); ?>
```

Comment: Shortcodes will not be processed and this could break quite a bit of plugin functionality.

Comment: Yeah, that works as long you don't have plugins that uses [---] tags in editor if I'm correct?

Comment: There's a `do_shortcode()` for that...

Comment: I've tried this now.

<?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); echo do_shortcode( $post->post_content ); endwhile ?>

removes my <p> tags but doesn't add any new, so it's not working the way I want it to work...

Comment: I got this working after deactivating the visual editor, however I find it very confusing of having a option to use HTML in the editor when it doesn't work fully...

Comment: Wordpress is made to work best for the least common denominator - the person with little to no html training. That's why the visual editor will mess up your custom `<p>` tags and breaks - it'll keep other tags it recognizes like divs, spans, etc, but it'll just convert p tags into double line breaks, and <br/> tags into single line breaks. Then when the theme runs the post content through "the_content" filters, it adds all the p and br tags back!

Answer (score 0):

The only way i've ever found (& maybe also the only one that actually works)

Install & activate the plugin [TinyMCE Advanced](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/)

Go to the plugin's settings page & check the box against "Stop removing `<p>` & `<br>` tags"

Go to your post's edit screen, switch between visual & html editor as often as you like & see the difference

Comment: Have you ever looked up the source to check what exactly is responsible for removing the paragraphs and linebreaks?

Comment: nope. must be somewhere in tinymce's javascript. It happens if i type in html editor, then switch to visual editor & then come back to html editor to find they are all gone

Comment: *"It happens if i type in html editor, then switch to visual editor & then come back to html editor to find they are all gone"* - That's a **feature**, not a **bug** in WordPress' TinyMCE implementation. Long story, short: **don't switch between Visual and HTML editors while editing posts. Pick one or the other, and stick with it.**

Comment: Personally, i don't like visual editors at all. But i've seen many bug reports for this thing & most of the time the clients would stick to "I don't care how it works, i just want it **fixed**"

Comment: In that case, you actually want to ask a different question: **How to prevent TinyMCE from stripping HTML tags when switching between HTML and Visual editors?** Of course, that question has been [asked and answered quite a few times](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=tinymce+remove+line+breaks). I think **[this answer should be what you need](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15666/3966)**.

Comment: seen that answer & many others, unfortunately nothing else worked. Went through the TinyMCE Advanced plugin's source & the js at line 228 in main file seems to be making the difference. Am i missing something?